# Parametrizar com RestShap

Tags: c#

Olá,
estou tentando passar um POST para minha WebApi usando RastSharp,
porém estou tendo dificuldade em passar os parâmetros...

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:18256");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/BancoWS", Method.POST);

//add os parametros
request.AddObject(empresa);
request.AddParameter("host", host);

request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { 
    resp.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;"; };

result = client.Execute<SalvarDto>(request);
```

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
>
> StatusCode: MethodNotAllowed

Aqui então tenho os detalhes da webApi

```
// POST: api/BancoWS
public SalvarDto Post(Empresa model, string host)
{
    SalvarDto banco = _bancoRepository.GerarBanco(model, host);
    SalvarDto dto = _bancoRepository.GerarBD((Banco)banco.Model);

    return dto;
}
```

Se eu remover o parâmetro '*host*'aí sim tenho sucesso, porem ele nesse caso é necessário, ai tenho esse problema ai cujo não chega o valor no método *Post*.

Comment: Depende de como está a definição da sua rota, provavelmente o parâmetro host está sendo enviado na URL e por isso o problema de `MethodNowAllowed`. Como você pretende receber este parâmetro? Na URL mesmo ou com formdata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que você está passando *host* ele será integrado à URL, dessa forma:
`api/BancoWS?host=valor`.
Sendo assim, para receber o valor corretamente talvez você precise explicitar com `[FromUri]`

```cs
public SalvarDto Post([FromBody]Empresa model, [FromUri]string host)
{
    SalvarDto banco = _bancoRepository.GerarBanco(model, host);
    SalvarDto dto = _bancoRepository.GerarBD((Banco)banco.Model);

    return dto;
}
```